# Hashtable, HashMap, HashSet , hash table concept in Java collection framework

Tags: java, hash, hashmap, hashtable, hashset

I am learning Java Collection Framework and got moderated understanding. Now, when I am going a bit further I got some doubts in: `HashMap`, `HashSet`, `Hashtable`.

The Javadoc for `HashMap` says:

> Hash table based implementation of the Map interface. This
>   implementation provides all of the optional map operations, and
>   permits null values and the null key.

The Javadoc for `HashSet` says:

> This class implements the Set interface, backed by a hash table
>   (actually a HashMap instance). It makes no guarantees as to the
>   iteration order of the set; in particular, it does not guarantee that
>   the order will remain constant over time.

The Javadoc for `Hashtable` says:

> This class implements a hash table, which maps keys to values. Any
>   non-null object can be used as a key or as a value.

It is confusing that all of them implement the `hash table`. Do they implement the **concept** of **hash table**?

It seems that all these are related to each other, but I am not able to fully understand it.

Can anyone help me understand this concept in simple language.

Answer (score 81, accepted):

Java's `Set` and `Map` interfaces specify two very different collection types. A `Set` is just what it sounds like: a collection of distinct (non-equal) objects, with no other structure. A `Map` is, conceptually, also just what it sounds like: a mapping from a set of objects (the distinct keys) to a collection of objects (the values). `Hashtable` and `HashMap` both implement `Map`, `HashSet` implements `Set`, and they all use hash codes for keys/objects contained in the sets to improve performance.

**`Hashtable` and `HashMap`**

`Hashtable` is a legacy class that almost always should be avoided in favor of `HashMap`. They do essentially the same thing, except most methods in `Hashtable` are synchronized, making individual method calls thread-safe.<sup>1</sup> You have to provide your own synchronization or other thread safety mechanism if you are using multiple threads and `HashMap`.

The problem with `Hashtable` is that synchronizing each method call (which is a not-insignificant operation) is usually the wrong thing. Either you don't need synchronization at all or, from the point of the view of the application logic, you need to synchronize over transactions that span multiple method calls. Since it was impossible to simply remove the method-level synchronization from `Hashtable` without breaking existing code, the Collections framework authors needed to come up with a new class; hence `HashMap`. It's also a better name, since it becomes clear that it's a kind of `Map`.

Oh, if you do need method-level synchronization, you still shouldn't use `Hashtable`. Instead, you can call [`Collections.synchronizedMap()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Collections.html#synchronizedMap(java.util.Map)) to turn any map into a synchronized one. Alternatively, you can use `ConcurrentHashMap`, which, according to [the docs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html): "obeys the same functional specification as `Hashtable`" but has better performance and additional functionality (such as `putIfAbsent()`).

<sup>1</sup> <sub>There are other differences (less significant, in my view) such as `HashMap` supporting `null` values and keys.</sub>

**`HashSet`**

In terms of functionality, `HashSet` has nothing to do with `HashMap`. It happens to use a `HashMap` internally to implement the `Set` functionality. For some reason, the Collections framework developers thought it would be a good idea to make this internal implementation detail part of the public specification for the class. (This was an error, in my view.)

Comment: this is one of the most insightful answers that resolves the confusion i had. thank you ted hopp! I was like, why is Hashtable not camel case & synchronized..., but HashMap/HashSet camel case and synchronized; and your answer explains it.

Answer (score 7):

Hashtable was an old class that was created before Java had generics. It's only around still for backwards compatibility. Use HashMap instead.

Use HashSet when you don't need to map keys to values. It's built on the same algorithm as hash tables, but it is used for a fundamentally different purpose.

Comment: @EJP: Could you please help me understand a bit more? Your answers to my previous questions (Yes I **do** remember) help clear the understanding.

Comment: @EJP : Is it correct to conclude that internally all these implement the concept of  "Hash table" , although the purpose of these classes are for different purposes?

Comment: Since generics were introduced, `Hashtable` has also been a generic class.

Answer (score 4):

HashMap and HashTable both inherits Map interface.and have almost same working and properties.But the major differences are as follows:-

1.Hashmap is an unordered map of key and value pairs.And we can have the null key or value pairs inside a hashmap.Also a hashmap is unsynchronized(i.e. not thread safe multiple threads can access and modify it at the same time.)But we can externally make a hashmap thread-safe.So if we are not considering the synchronization issues then hashmap is preferable.

2.HashTable:- A synchronized hashMap(i.e. a thread safe hashmap).But the keys and value pairs in this case never ever be null.In a Hashtable we specify an object that is used as a key, and the value we want to associate to that key. The key is then hashed, and the resulting hash code is used as the index at which the value is stored within the table

3.HashSet:-A hashset  inherits set interface and in the end its also based on hashtable(or we can say deeply connected to our hashmap only)but in this case the key's and values pairs are always unique no duplicate values allowed.but null key values are allowed.Objects are inserted based on their hash code.

In a conclusion we can say all the three collections have connected to Map interface on and all.

Answer (score 0):

Hashtable is synchronized but HashMap is not, but you can make HashMap synchronize with help of method Collections.synchronizedMap() . Hashtable, HashMap and HashSet are woking based on Hash Table data structure. You can use one null key and which kind of null values you want for HashMap but Hashtable does not allow null key or null values. Basically under HashSet is working HashMap where value is Object hence HashSet values are unique because HashMap keys are unique. So for putting key value pair in Hashmap or Hashtable or putting element to HashSet you need to ovveride hashcode and equals methods from Object class to correct working of this implementations. This is because under this implementations are working Hash Table algorithm and hashcode, equals is required to put values in right bucket. Its important to know that you need to use as keys String or any other wrapper class such us Integer, this is because this objects are immutable and they can be good keys for this implementations or you can create your own immutable class and use it as key. Use immutable objects as key is good practise because after creation they cant change their state hence the hashcode is same always.